# Converting a midi file to Snap! XML file

Tags: python

I need help with something involving a python script that converts a midi file into a XML file that Snap! can read. The only issue is, is that the extension that I am using to read the midi file doesn't like me using the note attribute (mido). Here's my python script so far:

```
import mido
from mido import MidiFile
for cNote in MidiFile('HSSWake.mid').play():
output = "<block s=\"doPlayNote\"><l>" + str(cNote.note) + "</l><l>" + str(cNote.time) + "</l></block>"

print(output)
input("") #Pause the program
```

It says `"Message" object has no attribute 'note'` which is not true since the 'note' attribute is in the documentation. Either I need to make an extension to the module, or I will abandon this since I don't know any more modules that could help.

Edit: Here's the midi that I'm using: https://mega.nz/file/Pk0SUZbT#aJm1U3ZqKvmBcolGk87j72URduBbvrKEo1Aic5gFH6w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very first message in your MIDI file is a `program_change` message, which does not have a `note` attribute:

```
program_change channel=0 program=0 time=0
```

The messages following it, however, have a `note` attribute:

```
note_on channel=0 note=60 velocity=63 time=0
note_on channel=0 note=82 velocity=12 time=0.09302325581395349
note_on channel=0 note=98 velocity=13 time=0.03488372093023256
note_off channel=0 note=98 velocity=64 time=0.03488372093023256
note_on channel=0 note=48 velocity=24 time=0.03488372093023256
note_on channel=0 note=96 velocity=12 time=0
...
```

So, it's your very first message that's raising an exception. One solution would be to just consume the first message from the message iterator, and then iterate through all the ones after it:

```
def main():
    import mido
    from mido import MidiFile

    messages = MidiFile("HSSWake.mid").play()
    _ = next(message)

    for message in messages:
        # do stuff with message

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

However, I didn't sit through and look at EVERY single message in your MIDI, so it could be that there are other messages that occur later on which also don't have a `note` attribute. In that case, you could skip any messages which don't have a `note` attribute in the loop:

```
def main():
    import mido
    from mido import MidiFile

    for message in MidiFile("HSSWake.mid").play():
        try:
            print(message.note)
        except AttributeError:
            print("Skipping message without 'note' attribute...")
            continue

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Alternatively, instead of a `try-except` block, you could just look at each message's type to figure out if it has a `note` attribute. Basically, just skip all messages that are not `note_on` messages:

```
for message in MidiFile("HSSWake.mid").play():
        if message.type != "note_on":
            continue
        print(message.note)
```

This means you will only print the `note` attribute of `note_on` messages. All other message types (even ones like `note_off` which have a `note` attribute) are excluded.

Comment: I don't think there are any more messages since the midi was converted from an mp3. Thanks!